# How to solve Ubuntu dedicated server date and time problem with litecoind?

Tags: 14.04, time

I installed litecoin daemon on my dedicated server (Ubuntu 14). I set the configuration in `.litecoin/litecoin.conf` like this:

```
server=1
rpcuser=test
rpcpassword=testpassword
rpcallowip=XX.XX.XXX.XXX
rpcport=9332
daemon=1
```

Whenever I run `./litecoind` I get this error

```
Warning: Please check that your computer's date and time are correct!
If your clock is wrong, Litecoin Core will not work properly.
```

I checked my Ubuntu date and time and I found it normal.
In other servers the daemon is running.
But in this one I'm getting this error.
Any solutions?

Comment: To **close voters** Ubuntu 14.04 reaches end of life in April 2019, one year from now.

Comment: I have some experience with algorithms for distributed consensus but not specifically with crypto-currencies or LiteCoin, so I'm asking out of a hunch: Does the error message appear right away or after some time? How did you set the system time on this machine? Does it use a network time service of some sort to synchronise time and work around hardware clock skew?

Comment: It appears after some seconds from running ./litecoind
The second question i think so